# problem embedding flash in webpage

Tags: html, flash

I am not sure whats going wrong but when I am using a flash file in the web page when I am setting size

style="width: 445px; height: 386px"

white strips are embedding sideways automaticaaly,,

while using the same page with size

width="450" height="440"

no white strips appear.

It might be the problem associated with the aspect ratio.

Is there any way to  set these white strps to transparent????

or  to remove these strips?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can we see a link? Or some code? It appears to be an aspect ratio problem because the width and height are definitely a different aspect ratio in your second scenario. Or if the white strips are the flash stage, you can also set wmode to transparent, and the html background will show through.